# Passing environment variables not working with Docker

Tags: linux, docker

I am learning how to pass environment variables to Docker containers. While the following works fine,

---

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM ubuntu
ENV USERNAME='david'
CMD echo "username = $USERNAME"
```

**Build & run commands**

```
docker build . -t enviro
docker run -d enviro
```

**docker ps -a** gives

```
2a3a69aa7868        enviro              "/bin/sh -c 'echo \"u…"
```

**docker logs 2a3a69aa7868** gives

```
username = david
```

---

The following doesn't work

---

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM ubuntu
CMD echo "username = $USERNAME"
```

**Build & run commands**

```
docker build . -t enviro
docker run -d enviro -e USERNAME='david'
```

Here the run command gives this,

```
docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: 
  container_linux.go:348: starting container process caused "exec: \"-e\": 
  executable file not found in $PATH": unknown.
```

While **docker ps -a** gives

```
249cb045c26a        enviro              "-e USERNAME=david"
```

**docker logs 249cb045c26a** gives nothing

---

Any idea, what is going on here? Why is the environment variable not being passed?

Answer (score 95, accepted):

OK, I got it. Instead of the following,

```
docker run -d enviro -e USERNAME='david'
```

it must be like this

```
docker run -d -e USERNAME='david' enviro
```

No idea, why docker requires the environment variable before the image's name though.

Comment: This is because everything after the image name is sent as parameters to the entrypoint script. Which by default is /bin/sh -c

Comment: Man, I was wondering SO much about exactly the same thing. Your answer is absolutely golden.