# asp.net core override connection strings via ENV variables

Tags: c#, docker, asp.net-core

I have an asp.net core API 2.2 implemented. I have created a docker image. I would like to override connection strings in appsettings.json file.

Is there any way to do it? I tried via environment variables when I start the container with command `docker container run -e "ConnectionStrings:DefaultConnection={...here goes the connection string}"`

I have also `builder.AddEnvironmentVariables();` in my Startup.cs but connection string in my appsetting.json is not replaced.

I checked it inside the container, appsetting.json is there but the values are not replaced.

Any other way how to do such cases? Thx.

Comment: Replace `:` with `__` (2x `_`).

Comment: @KirkLarkin I have tried it. It does not work. `docker run -d -e ConnectionStrings__CommonDbConnection='Server=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=CommonDb;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true' -e ConnectionStrings__SharedDbConnection='Server=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=SharedDb;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true'`
any other suggestion?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

For `-e`, it will override the system environment which will change the connectionstring when you retrive from code, it will not affect the content in `appsettings.json`.

For example

1. Assume you have a `appsettings.json` like

   ```
   {
       "ConnectionStrings": {
           "DefaultConnection": "Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=aspnet-TestDockerConfiguration-416C6FD2-3531-42D6-9EDE-18AC45901208;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
       },
       "Logging": {
           "LogLevel": {
           "Default": "Warning"
           }
       },
       "AllowedHosts": "*"
   }
   ```
2. Retrive the connectionstring by `_configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")` like

   ```
   public class HomeController : Controller
   {
       private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;
       public HomeController(IConfiguration configuration)
       {
           _configuration = configuration;
       }
       public IActionResult Index()
       {
           return Ok(_configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"));
           //return View();
       }
   }
   ```
3. For `docker run -it -p 8888:80 dockerconfiguration`, it will return `"Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=aspnet-TestDockerConfiguration-416C6FD2-3531-42D6-9EDE-18AC45901208;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"` for Index Action
4. For `docker run -it -p 8888:80 dockerconfiguration -e "ConnectionStrings:DefaultConnection"="testsqlstring"`, it will return `testsqlstring`
5. So, if you only want to override the value in `appsettings.json` during runtime, you just need to specify like Step 4

If you prefer change the appsettings.json file in docker container, you could follow steps below

1. Install `vi` command with  `apt-get install vim -y`
2. Run `docker exec -it 43ea835776dd /bin/bash` to go into container
3. Run `ls` to list files and find the `appsettings.json`
4. Run `vi appsettings.json` to modify the content
5. Run `cat appsettings.json` to check the content whether it is changed
6. Run `exit` and access the `Home/Index` to check the result.

Comment: `"ConnectionStrings:DefaultConnection"="testsqlstring"` is not working on Linux. Microsoft recommends using double underscores which works on all platforms like so: `"ConnectionStrings__DefaultConnection"="testsqlstring"`

Comment: Also I needed to Add `.AddEnvironmentVariables()` to my configuration builder.

Comment: The command must have the container name after the environment variables as such:
`docker run -it -p 8888:80 -e "ConnectionStrings:DefaultConnection"="testsqlstring" dockerconfiguration`
Solution was found from article: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50181031/passing-environment-variables-not-working-with-docker

Answer (score 5):

appsetting.json never gets changed, however based on the hierarchy, variables values get overridden. Take a look at the examples at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-2.2#conventions . It works pretty well. Perhaps just to be sure that you didn't break something because of command line execution, you can try to assign environment variables via docker-compose. The rule of thumb is that the pattern that you use for the "key" must match (with the help of `__` instead of `:`)what you have in the json file, so that it gets overridden.

Answer (score 1):

Tried without the quotes for the ConnectionStrings section and it worked (on a PowerShell console.

```sh
docker run -d -p 8080:80 --name letscosmosweb -e ConnectionStrings__ProductsDbContext=$key letscosmosweb:v1
```

`$key` variable contains the connection string

Answer (score 0):

**If you're using `docker-compose`**

Besides specifying the variable in `.env`, don't forget to also set it in `environments` section of the `docker-compose.yml`. It got me :)