# Docker build not recognizing environment variable passed as `build-arg`

Tags: docker, environment-variables, docker-build

I've looked at [Can we pass ENV variables through cmd line while building a docker image through dockerfile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31198835/can-we-pass-env-variables-through-cmd-line-while-building-a-docker-image-through)  which shows me how to pass an environment variable with `docker build`. After seeing that the environment variable wasn't being defined, I looked at [Passing environment variables not working with Docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50181031/passing-environment-variables-not-working-with-docker) but this concerns passing environment variables through `docker run`.

Here's my `prod.Dockerfile`:

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04

ARG SSH_PRIVATE_KEY

RUN echo "Key is $SSH_PRIVATE_KEY."
```

and the `docker build` command:

```
docker build -f prod.Dockerfile \
             --build-arg SHH_PRIVATE_KEY="$(cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa)" \
             .
```

Resulting output:

```
Key is .
```

Yet the output of `cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa` is:

```
-----BEGIN OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----
...
-----END OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `SHH_PRIVATE_KEY` with `SSH_PRIVATE_KEY`.

```
docker build -f prod.Dockerfile \
   --build-arg SSH_PRIVATE_KEY="$(cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa)" \
   .
```

Comment: Dang, can't believe I kept correcting `SHH` to `SSH` in my head. Thanks a ton.